# Implement predefined Open Command in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, command

how do I bind my own written Open Command called MyOpenCommand in MyOpenCommand.cs to the predefined Open Command provided by WPF?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DokumentViewerSample.Commands
{
    class MyOpenCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //Some opening logic!
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, I would create a reference in Window.Resources defining a key, 
something like:

```
 <Window.Resources>
       <local:MyOpenCommand x:Key="cmd1" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

and finally bind the command to the command attribute of the control.

But how can I use the predefined Open Command? I know, that i can define BindingResources. Something like:

```
 <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Open" CanExecute="Some_Handler"
                            Executed="Some_Handler2"></CommandBinding>
 </Window.CommandBindings>
```

But here I would create Callback Methods in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file and I have the feeling, that this is not right.

I would be really thankfull if you could show me the best practice version (:

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you want to use the command later by an Control in the Windows?

Comment: Yes! I Want a Control to use it

Comment: Open *is* a command. MyOpenCommand is another one. What exaclty are you trying to do? You can't replace the Open command with your own one but you can *handle* the Open command that is being raised.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to use a Command from a Controll I normally define it in the view Model.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public MyOpenCommand MyCommand { get; set; } = new MyOpenCommand();
//...
```

And then set the view Model

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ViewModel();            
 }
```

Than I'm able to set the Command Binding like:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Open" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

By the way for this the MyOpenCommand class must be set public.

If you want to use CommandBindings, may be see Matt Hamilton article on this: 
[matthamilton.net/commandbindings-with-mvvm](http://matthamilton.net/commandbindings-with-mvvm)

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but that's not exactly what i wanted to know. I wanted to know how I can use the predefined ApplicationComands.Open and bind my Methods (CanExecute and Execute) from the MyOpenCommand class to the EventHandler? Because i do not want to store the method definitions and logic in the mainwindow.xaml.cs (:

Comment: I think in that case the artical matthamilton.net/commandbindings-with-mvvm may help